# When buying fuel in Peru service stations, do you have to give an ID?

Tags: paperwork, peru, taxes

Sorry, but not exactly sure where to ask this questions, but if there are any locals from Peru, I thought would try here. Not exactly a travel question, but hoping to use local knowledge.

I am working on a project passing data from service stations in Peru to SUNNAT (the Peru tax dept).

In the electronic receipt information for Factura and Boleta, there are mandatory fields called things like 'Numero de documento de identidad del adquirente o usuario' and 'Tipo de documento de identidad del adquirente o usuario'. There is also 'Apellidos y nombres o denominación o razón social según RUC. Datos del receptor de la boleta de venta (“cliente”, “comprador”).'

My Spanish is very limited, but think this means that when you get a receipt, it has customer details such as ID number.

When you buy gas for your car or truck in Peru, do you have to provide your ID?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the information you mention is required only for tax-deductible or proof-of-purchase receipts  of the type one might require if refueling a company/leasing car. I.e. they are more of an invoice than a receipt. The hint is given by the mention of `razón social` which is legalese for `company name`. Now I've never refueled in Peru, but I do have  in both Argentina and Uruguay. I was never asked for ID for the purpose of filling in a receipt. I have however seen such invoices been handed out.  Usually people who do need them will request them specifically. The rest of us will get normal cash-register receipts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you still need the information but let me translate what each sentence means.

*'Numero de documento de identidad del adquirente o usuario' = User DNI (Personal ID,Identity card).*

*'Tipo de documendo de identidad del adquiriente o usuario' = Type of identity card of the user*

*'Apellidos y nombres o denominación o razón social según RUC' = Last and First name or company name according to RUC("Unique Taxpayer Identification Number")*

*'Datos del receptor de la boleta de venta (“cliente”, “comprador”)' = Information of the receipt ''receiver?''*

**Not sure about this last one.... of what you are asking.**

People rarely give their ID when they buy gas, however in the receipt (Boleta de Venta) the fields exist.. Usually people just buy and put their names and that's it.. and that's if they ask for a receipt.. (we rarely ask for it). Now regarding the RUC("Unique Taxpayer Identification Number") is when you aks for a receipt in the name of the company usually in this type of receipt you do fill out all the information as its mandatory and will be checked by the SUNAT.

Hope it helped!

PD. I'm local